# Warm up assets compilation for testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, integration-testing

I'm running my tests on CI server. There is a nasty timeout issues that I occasionally encounter when the test runner first visit the index page. This is where the assets compilation being kicked off. Due to the amount of assets I have, this usually lead to a Timeout error while Chrome browser trying to open the web.

Is there a way I can warm up assets compilation prior to test run so the request is completed within a short time?

Answer (score 0):

Seem like it's possible by using capybara helpers:

1. Create a rake task (puts in `lib/tasks`):

   ```
   namespace :test do
     desc 'Warm up assets'
     task :warmup => :environment do
       require 'capybara/rails'
       Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
       Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
         Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
       end

       include Capybara::DSL

       puts "Warm up assets compilation by requesting root_path"
       visit "/" rescue nil
     end
   end
   ```
2. Run this command to warm up prior to test:

   ```
   bundle exec rake test:warmup RAILS_ENV=test
   ```